# UI for displaying items horizontally instead of vertically like in datagrid

Tags: wpf

I want to achieve my UI something like below:-

```
                Item 1     Item 2     Item3    Item 4
    Heading 1:    AA        AA1        AA2      AA3
    Heading 2:    20        10         11       89
    Heading 3:    10        11         89        7
    Heading 4:   Expand     Expand    Expand    Expand
```

Where the items will come from the collection.PropertyName will be displayed as heading & the values.Each heading will be of specific type & will be validated seperately.Also there will be a horizontal scrollbar from Item 1 to Item 4 visible all the times.In the fourth row there is an Expander control.When we click on expander width & height increases.

Currently I have done this using one grid & one items control.One for the heading & one for the Grid like layout..Aligned them through SharedSize group.But issue is coming when I increase the number of characters in a cell to large extent & delete it,layout completely got destroyed..

Wpf Code:-

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
            <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ExpanderHeight"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Name" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label Content="Age" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Label Content="Nothing" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"  />
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl2" Grid.Column="1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ExpanderHeight"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MyWidth"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox  Text="{Binding Index}" Background="Gray"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                            <Expander Grid.Row="3"   FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  ExpandDirection="Down" Header="MyCustom">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Test11119999999999999677777"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="123333"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="90000"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    namespace BindingGroupSample
    {
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Temp> list1 = new ObservableCollection<Temp>();
    ObservableCollection<Temp> list2 = new ObservableCollection<Temp>();  

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


         for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)    
         {
            // list1.Add(new Temp() { Index = i });
             list2.Add(new Temp() { Index = i,Name = "AA" + i + i ,Age=i*2});
             list1.Add(new Temp() { Index = i, Name = "AA" + i + i, Age = i * 2 });   
         }  

        ItemsControl2.ItemsSource = list2;

        //ItemsControl1.ItemsSource = list1;

    }

    private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // ItemsControl1.Items.Refresh();
    }

   }



public class Temp
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

}

I cannot achieve this with element binding as the headings will be somewhat displaced with the items value.

Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Giving width to index,name and age textboxes will solve your problem right..?

Comment: Actually No,i dont want to hardcode width..

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in your binding.....

I have binded textbox width with the datatemplate width... not hardcoded width anywhere...

```
<DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="RowHeight"/>
                                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ExpanderHeight"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MyWidth"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Index}" Background="Gray" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}"  MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Age}"  MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                <Expander Grid.Row="3"   FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  ExpandDirection="Down" Header="MyCustom"  MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualWidth}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Test11119999999999999677777" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="123333"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="90000"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but that is an alternative solution,i will prefer to increase the width when we open the expander control so that my control does not look smaller..

Comment: <TextBlock Text="Test11119999999999999677777" TextWrapping="Wrap"/> i have added TextWrapping="Wrap" if you remove this property or change it to NoWrap.. then your contol will increase the width along with expander

Comment: Yes that I have added just like that,but actually inside my expander,a big control will be displayed.I have to increase the width as our requirement is like that only.So i am looking for a solution where i can reset all the textboxes to allign together whenever we delete the text inside the textbox.